# FakeItEasy: Reset Fake Calls History / Ignore Call

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, fakeiteasy

I would like to reset a Fake Calls History or ignore a Call.

The fake asserted method is called in the Init method in the tested class constructor and I want to ignore this call because it's not part of the tested action.

Here an example:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private MyFakedClass myFakedObject;
    private SUT sut;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        myFakedObject = A.Fake<MyFakedClass>();
        sut = new SUT(myFakedObject); //constructor calls myFakedObject.AssertedMethod()
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        sut.TestedMethod(); //TestedMethod calls myFakedObject.AssertedMethod() again...
        A.CallTo(() => myFakedObject.AssertedMethod()).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once); 
//...So this is false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I love @forsvarir's answer. I would be inclined to think that the call from within the constructor is significant.

However, if you really need to do this:

When **FakeItEasy version ≥ 3.2.0**, you can use `ClearRecordedCalls`:

```
Fake.ClearRecordedCalls(fake);
```

When **2.0.0 ≤ FakeItEasy version < 3.2.0**, consider the forsvarir's subtraction method ([FakeItEasy: Reset Fake Calls History / Ignore Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095019/fakeiteasy-reset-fake-calls-history-ignore-call/29096765#29096765)).

When **FakeItEasy version < 2.0.0**, you can use scopes:

```
[Test]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    using (Fake.CreateScope())
    {
        sut.TestedMethod(); // calls myFakedObject.AssertedMethod() again
        A.CallTo(() => myFakedObject.AssertedMethod())
         .MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
    }
}
```

Using the scope causes `MustHaveHappened` to look only at calls made from within the scope.

You could also create the scope in the `TestInitialize` and dispose of it in the `TestCleanup` method, if you wanted to keep the `using` outside of all your test methods.

Comment: I was impressed that someone knew how to do this, then I saw that it was you @Blair Conrad! Still a little impressed though.

Answer (score 4):

This feels wrong to me.  Typically I would expect the cost of object creation to be part of the expectations of the tests for that object.  Obviously, it depends upon what your `AssertedMethod` does, however, would your test really still be valid if your constructor didn’t call it?  Would your SUT be in the expected state that your class needs?

I can’t see anything in the fakeiteasy framework to allow you to reset the count, although as I’ve said, this doesn’t feel like the right thing to do so I wasn’t really expecting to find it.  It seems like a simple way to achieve what you seem to be trying to do, whilst still acknowledging at least at a `TestClass` level that you know there is a call in the constructor/init would be something like this:

```
const int InitAssertedMethodCalls = 1;

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    sut.TestedMethod(); 
    A.CallTo(() => myFakedObject.AssertedMethod())
             .MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Times(1 + InitAssertedMethodCalls )); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @forsvarir. In my case the test is effectively still valid even if the constructor didn't call the assertedMethod but I agree with your point of view.